# As3 Regex or alternative to split strings

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, replace, split

i have a html page , i use regex to remove all html tags from the page and extract the text using the below code.

```
var foo = loader.data.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
var bar:Array = foo.split("Total");
foo = foo.split(bar[0]);
trace(foo);
```

And using the same code lines below the replace method i remove every string before the word **"TOTAL"**. It does the job perfectly but now i want to apply and other split to get contents after **"TOTAL"** and remove the Content after **"BYTES"**.

So when i try to  split it up again with

```
var bar2:Array = foo.split("BYTES");
foo = foo.split(bar2[0]);
```

Flash returns a error saying SPLIT is a not a  valid method :S
I tried several other ways , ( REPLACE ) but still flash produces errors.

Can Anyone help me to get through this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

".split()" is a method of String. When you did the assignment below:

```
foo = foo.split(bar[0]);
```

foo became an array, and thus the call

```
var bar2:Array = foo.split("BYTES");
```

was being made to an array, which is invalid (no such method)

What you want instead is this:

```
var foo = loader.data.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
trace(foo);
var result = foo.split("Total")[1].split("BYTES")[0];
trace(result);
```